# How to select the same rows from list of data frames?

Tags: r

I have a list consisting of two data frames with the same dimensions. I would like to choose the same specific rows from them.

```
df1 = data.frame(A = 1:5, B = 6:10)
df2 = data.frame(A = 11:15, B = 16:20)

ls = list(df1, df2)

idx = sample(1:5, size = 3)

# code below doesn't work
train = ls[][idx, ]
test = ls[][-idx, ]
```

Now I get these errors:

> Error in ls[][idx, ] : incorrect number of dimensions
>
> Error in ls[][-idx, ] : incorrect number of dimensions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is a `list`, we can use `lapply` to loop over the list.  Specify the `,` at the end if we don't want anonymous function or else by default, it would take it as column index

```
lapply(ls, `[`, idx,)
lapply(ls, `[`, -idx,)
```

With lambda/anonymous function

```
lapply(ls, function(x) x[idx, ])
lapply(ls, function(x) x[-idx,])
```

`ls` is a function name, so it is better not to use function names to name objects